# Javascript If Else If statement issues

Tags: if-statement

I am having an issue with an If Else If statement in my code.  Basically, I have four four element arrays (Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4).  The value of a variable (frameSizeClass) taken from drop down menu will determine which of the arrays to use (via the If Else If statement), and another variable will determine which element in the array to return to a text box.
What is happening is that regardless of what the value of frameSizeClass is, it acts as if the variable=1, and return values from array Table1.  If I comment out the other portions of the If Else If and test the individual If statements, they work, but not as a combined If Else If.  I'm at a loss and would welcome any help.  Code is below.

```
    if (frameSizeClass = 1){
        baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable1[ratedSpeedClass];
    } else if (frameSizeClass = 2){
        baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable2[ratedSpeedClass];
    } else if (frameSizeClass = 3){
        baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable3[ratedSpeedClass];
    } else if (frameSizeClass = 4){
        baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable4[ratedSpeedClass];
    }
```

Comment: `frameSizeClass = 1` is an assignment statement. For comparison, you need to do `frameSizeClass == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most programming languages the `=` operator means assignment and `==` means equal.

The correct code would look like this

```js
if (frameSizeClass == 1){
    baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable1[ratedSpeedClass];
} else if (frameSizeClass == 2){
    baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable2[ratedSpeedClass];
} else if (frameSizeClass == 3){
    baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable3[ratedSpeedClass];
} else if (frameSizeClass == 4){
    baseLubeIntVal = greaseTable4[ratedSpeedClass];
}
```